# Send BASE64 file from Backbone.js model to browser

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a BASE64 encoded file in a backbone model.

Looking something like this ( `console.log(model.toJSON());` ):

```
Attachments: Array[1]
    0: Object
        Content: "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iaiA8PC9UeXBlL..."
        ContentLength: 29512
        ContentType: "application/octet-stream"
        Name: "Notification.pdf"
```

How do I send this to the browser as a forced download on a click event? 
I want to avoid going back to the server to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different options, all involving [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

If you just want to do a quick download and don't care about what the filename will be, then you can have your JS do this:

```
window.location = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJ...';
```

However, if you want to be able to specify a filename for the download, then you need to fall back onto new HTML5 features, and an `<a>` tag.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJ...';
a.download = 'Filename.pdf';
a.click();
```

This will work on older browsers, but since the `download` attribute is new in HTML5, they will download the file without a proper filename.

Comment: That works great thanks. Its an app for internal use so no problem specifying HTML5 browsers only :)